# How do I assign a Data Connection extract to a different source?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-data-connection

I'd like to change the source that is associated with a Data Connection extract. Is this possible, without re-creating the extract in the new source?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create a new extract, and simply copy over the sync configuration yaml by clicking the `Advanced` option.

Additionally, you should verify that the settings on the left-hand side are as follows:

[image: foundry extract settings panel]